# Combine imports in one file in Solidity

Tags: solidity

Is there a tool like the subject for Solidity. Let's say I have a contract with import and that import has three imports etc. I'd like to combine all of them into one file and play with it in Remix, for example.

I know how to make it manually.

Comment: I think http://browserify.org makes more sense in this question since you also want a loader to be able to read from `node_modules` folder that were installed with npm or ethpm

Comment: @rstormsf I'd like to combine only .sol files from all corresponding files into one new file. I agree that require.js is not the right analogy

Comment: Well, if you use something like openZeppelin installed from npm, u really want it to be able to load all of it from the right folders

Comment: I need to copy and paste a complex contract to Remix and it doesn't support folder structure afaik

Comment: I don't have much exposure to remix. Is there a possibility of executing the contract's definition in JSON file? If yes then we can generate it using solc compiler. That JSON will have ABIs of all dependent contracts. Let me know if this can work out, I'll share the command.

Comment: @Sanchit, whatever works, it's interesting idea, yes I can generate compiled JSON files

Answer (score 6):

Use [sol-merger](https://github.com/RyuuGan/sol-merger). This works like a charm. It creates a separate folder and put the merged contracts there.

Comment: Thanks Aniket, yes this works like a charm.I tried and happy from result.

Comment: this worked so smooth. need to modify ```npm build-contracts``` command as per user directory structure and then see the charm 

Answer (score 3):

I'd also suggest you to try this - http://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_remixd_filesystem.html

This feature is currently an alpha version but it may help you.

Comment: It did work, thank you. although, if there are any shared files besides .sol files a page crash.

Comment: Eh, for verifying smart contract code on etherscan e.g. https://kovan.etherscan.io/verifyContract?a=0x6ce4837b86ee19feaaeee16e459cc131db9c342e I still need to have a flat file with all imports. May be you'll have ideas how to automate it

Comment: I just had a look, the idea I had is to generate JSON file combining definition of all contracts using solc compiler but I don't think it would work here. The combined JSON worked fine when I deployed contract with multiple imports in web3js but here, in this case, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

please have a look on : [solidity-flattener](https://github.com/BlockCatIO/solidity-flattener)

This script automatically traverses the dependency graph and outputs all of your imports in the correct order, ready to be pasted into the contract verifier.

Comment: I have a problem with this tool described here https://github.com/BlockCatIO/solidity-flattener/issues/37#issuecomment-596577107

Answer (score 0):

just for the information. I created a plugin for `VSCode` so you can use it instead of `sol-merger` because it is based on it under the hood.

Here is the link for plugin: [Solidity Contracts Merger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RyuuGan.sol-merger-vscode).

Hope you will like it.