# Error: Expected string literal (path), "*" or alias list

Tags: security, docker, tools

I m currently working on smart contracts and i m trying test the contracts i wrote. I am using smartbugs tool. So far, i have executed the following commands in the powershell,

git clone https://github.com/smartbugs/smartbugs.git
python -m venv venv
.\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
cd smartbugs
python -m sb -t conkas -f samples/contracts/SCbase/SupplyChain.sol

[image]

[image]

Here, after successful execution, the result file is generated. But i get the error stating,
Error: Expected string literal (path), "*" or alias list.
which is found inside the result file.

[image]

if i add path as
import "./samples/contracts/SCore/Ownable.sol";
or
import "samples/contracts/SCore/Ownable.sol";
Still i m getting error.
[image]

What should i do ? can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import "samples/contracts/SCore/Ownable.sol";
```

or

```
import "./samples/contracts/SCore/Ownable.sol";
```

There is an error in the path. It seems like you are using the wrong slash.

Comment: Tried both but i m still getting error. I have added the screenshot in the question section.

Comment: The new error shows that the file cannot be found at the directory you specify. Maybe this article can help you:
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/path-resolution.html#imports

Comment: initially i have give path import '../SCcore/Ownable.sol';
import '../SCaccesscontrol/CarParts_ManufacturerRole.sol';
import '../SCaccesscontrol/CarParts_DistributorRole.sol';
import '../SCaccesscontrol/RetailerRole.sol';
import '../SCaccesscontrol/CustomerRole.sol'; like this only in remix where the project executed correctly. But after bring the files to the system for performing security analysis the path shows error.

Comment: Without the context of security analysis, do you move the whole folder together? Or you can merge all the imports into one file if that is easier for you. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19626/combine-imports-in-one-file-in-solidity

Comment: I have downloaded it from remix as zip file, extracted it and i only copied contracts folder within the samples folder of the smartbugs folder. Path -> C:\Users\Ishwa\smartbugs\samples\contracts\SCbase\Supplychain.sol  But, now i tried placing the whole folder within the samples folder and still getting the error. Path -> C:\Users\Ishwa\smartbugs\samples\Ethereum-SupplyChain1\contracts\SCbase\SupplyChain.sol

Comment: I ll try merging too. Thank you so much for directing me.